# Schengen Visa Application - Family 2 US Passport, 1 Greencard - Hotel Itinerary

Tags: paperwork, schengen-visas, applications, proof-of-accommodation

We are a family of 3 people. Me and my dad hold a US passport, but my mom doesn't. We will all be traveling in a group.

Under Schengen visa, should the hotel be booked under her name? What if it is under mine or my dad's name? Could it be a reason for denial? The hotels are already booked and unfortunately not refundable, but I made it extra clear on my cover letter that it is for 3 people.

Comment: Is your mother’s family name the same as your father’s? Does the hotel booking state the number of guests? Is your mum applying in her own right or is your father paying for all/some of the costs? All other things being equal, and assuming the paperwork you submitted demonstrated travel as a family, IMHO I don’t see why this should be a reason to refuse. See eg 7.6 https://ec.europa.eu/home-affairs/sites/homeaffairs/files/policies/borders/docs/c_2010_1620_en.pdf#page57

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify. Putting on hold for now.